# In a repository with c#, poco's and ado.net what is best, one class for entire repository or several classes per entity?

Tags: c#, ado.net, repository-pattern, poco

I'm creating a repository for my project, actually a subset of it, with c#, poco's and old ado.net (no ORM's).
I've several entities and my repository will CRUD those through a DAL.
My DAL is IDisposable so I managed to open a connection to database when instantiate it and close that connection in Dispose method.
Now I want to know, should I have to use in repository one class per entity or one huge class for all of them?
The second approach will allow me to open connection, retrieve many entities as I want e then close it. The first one I've to open and close one connection per entity, like this:

```
 //One big class for all entities, opens one connection
 using(RepositoryForAll rfa = new RepositoryForAll())
 {
     Customer c = rfa.GetCustomer(Customerid);
     Order o = rfa.GetOrder(OrderId);
 }
 //closes the connection

 //One repository class per entity, also one connection
 using(RepositoryCustomer customers = new RepositoryCustomer())
 {
     var c = customers.Get(CustomerId);
 }
 //closes the connection for RepositoryCustomer

 using(RepositoryOrder orders = new RepositoryOrder())
 {
     var c = orders.Get(OrderId);
 }
 //closes the connection for RepositoryOrder
```

This makes sense?
I read about AggregateRoot in some book which suggests another approach.
This is a fairly simple example and my repository does not have to be that sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about a different solution? create your connection (or transaction, or unit of work) *outside* of the repository, and pass it to the repository.
like so-

```
using(var tx = new Transaction())
 {
     RepositoryCustomer customers = new RepositoryCustomer(tx)
     RepositoryOrder orders = new RepositoryOrder(tx)
     var c = customers.Get(CustomerId);
     var o = orders.Get(OrderId);
 }
```

(This is just a simple example, of course; I would recommend using some sort of an IoC mechanism instead of instantiating objects yourself.
Also you might want to read a little about the `Unit of work` concept, which may apply here)

Answer (score 0):

Organize classes in manageable groups.

In your case I think Order and Customer should belong to a OrderRepository.

A Product would go into a CatalogueRepository.

If classes need to be mocked when Unit Tested they go into their own Repository. That might be a PaymentRepository.

Comment: This is the Aggregate root I mentioned above, does not solve my problem... Thanks anyway!